# working with mongoDB and PHP (Laravel)

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm working with mongoDB and PHP (Laravel) and finding alot of difficulties in executing the complex queries on PHP (Laravel), all queries working smoothly on mongo Booster but when I execute them on PHP (Laravel) it really gives me tough time. Can any one help me out how could I execute them like raw queries on PHP (Laravel).

Comment: Are you using `jenssegers/laravel-mongodb` package or the `mongodb/mongodb` directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Raw queries in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions)

Sometimes you may need to use a raw expression in a query. These expressions will be injected into the query as strings, so be careful not to create any SQL injection points! To create a raw expression, you may use the `DB::raw` method:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                     ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))
                     ->where('status', '<>', 1)
                     ->groupBy('status')
                     ->get();
```

Another Example

```
$result = DB => collection('PMS')->raw(function ($collection){
    return $collection->aggregate(array(
        array( '$match' => array( "PanelID" => "A00898" ) ),
        array( '$project' => array( 'EventTS' => 1, 'MainsPower' => 1 ) ),
        array(
            '$unwind' => array(
                'path' => "$MainsPower",
                'includeArrayIndex' => "arrayIndex",
                'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays' => true
            )
        ),
        array(
            '$project' => array(
                '_id' => 0,
                'MainsPower' => 1,
                'timestamp' => array(
                    "$add" => array(
                        "$EventTS",
                        array( "$multiply" => array( 60000, "$arrayIndex" ) )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ));
});
```

Comment: If that help you mark the answer so someone else know it's helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may need to use a raw expression in a query. These expressions will be injected into the query as strings, so be careful not to create any SQL injection points! To create a raw expression, you may use the `DB::raw` method:

```
$result = DB::select(
  DB::raw('your query here')
);
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions)

Comment: Thanks! I will try this way too:-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes answers given by other is right but raw queries performing in Laravel is not good practice. Then why you are using Laravel Framework. You should use eloquent because if you change the db like mysql instead of mongo you need not to change quires. That's the power of Eloquent ORM.

Comment: *raw queries performing in Laravel is not good practice* - it is not true! There is many cases where using raw queries IS A GREAT approach.